# How does the SetTargetPath event in InstallShield Basic MSI work?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have a product that needs to install to multiple drives and directories, some of which can be customized. So I'm looking at how directories are changed at run-time in an InstallShield Basic MSI project. I see that the `DestinationFolder` and `InstallChangeFolder` dialogs work together to change the `INSTALLDIR` directory using a `SetTargetPath` event on the `OK` button press of `InstallChangeFolder`.

What I don't understand is why there is only one parameter to `SetTagetPath`. The `MsiSetTargetPath` function takes 2 parameters in addition to the installation handle, so I don't understand why the `SetTargetPath` event only takes 1. I want to set a specified directory variable to refer to the specified directory. That requires two parameters. How are they getting by with just one parameter?

I have read the [documentation on `SetTargetPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371697(v=vs.85).aspx) 3 times and it still doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the purpose of `SetTargetPath` is to transfer an updated value in a property to the directory variable of the same name, performing some validations on the old and new values (in the directory variable and property value respectively) in the process. Therefore it seems that transferring a new value into a directory variable takes place in two steps:

1. Set a property of the same name to the new value.
2. Call `SetTargetPath` providing the property name to copy the value from teh property into the directory.

In doing this, be aware that if the property is provided is brackets, it will be expected to reference another property name. So if the value to be copied to a directory variable is directly in the property, do not use brackets.

Comment: I have found the only way to Change the INSTALLDIR is reference it to another property then call SetTargetPath against that property. Just setting the value to another string works during the dialogs but doesn't work when comes to where the files are then installed.

Answer (score 0):

You want to research "file costing" (Cost Initialize, Cost Finalize).  Prior to costing you can use a Type 51 Set Property custom action.  After costing you have to use a Type 35 Set Directory custom action.  This is because costing needs to be recalculated.

I've noticed you've got a lot of MSI questions.  You might want to pick up a book such as Phil Wilson's The Definitive Guide to Windows Installer.  That and mentors are the best sources of information because there is so little training available in this area.

Comment: This is how I learn: jump into a new project with a barely-familiar technology so I'm in over my head, then just drink it all in until the water's around my knees :). I think I've got it down to chest level now. I've learned a lot with the help of SO and Google. Much faster than with a book, I think. My most remarkable accomplishment so far is a program to update InstallShield's MSI transforms for each instance, to also replace all the component GUIDs. Seems to make multi-instance installs work out pretty cleanly without having to duplicate everything 10 times.

Comment: Does my answer concerning SetTargetPath show good understanding of what's going on? I am both setting properties and calling `SetTargetPath` for those properties after Cost Finalize because I think that's what I saw the standard Change Destination dialogs doing. It seems to behave well and the logs look good.